# get solana transaction-history for a given address - based on date range

Tags: blockchain, solana

I want to use Rust or Python to retrieve historical Solana transactions for a given wallet - in a specific date range.

There is the `get_confirmed_signature_for_address2()` which returns signatures for a given address, with an option to get signatures before a given signature.

But how can I find historical transactions using a specific timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getBlockTime`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblocktime) will give you the estimated time for a given block

[`getBlock`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblock) will give the list of signatures in a specific block

[`getSignatures`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress) will get you the signatures for an address 1000 at a time, before or after a given signature.

Combine them with a binary search algorithm to find nearby timestamp

Comment: calling the getSignatures function will return the newest 1000 signatures for an address, and then I can take the oldest one to get the next 1000 signatures for that address, and so on. I didn't understand how I can use the above to get an older signature for the given address without moving back 1000 transactions each time

Comment: So you can use `getBlockTime` to get estimated time at different blocks. Then when you find the specific time you want, you can use `getBlock` to get the signatures in the block. Then you can use `before` and `after` with `getSIgnatures` to find the specific signatures for an address at that time

Comment: oh, so the transaction signature I use as the "before" input doesn't need to be related to the account I query, just some transaction made at some time... so I can use getRecentBlockhash  to get the latest block and then I subtract some number from it until I get a block from a relevant time?  Is there some rule of thumb of how many blocks I should subtract for a day / week / month?

Comment: A block is roughly 400ms. You can use that to estimate, or do what I mentioned above to find the right time

Comment: @JacobCreech How to get transaction history of one specific token?